# SQLite Android time query

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working with Android App and want to make a query to my SQLite db.

I have column "time" with text type.

```
ID = 49, date = 2021-12-15, time = 03:43:16, ...
ID = 50, date = 2021-12-15, time = 03:54:35, ...
ID = 51, date = 2021-12-15, time = 03:56:32, ...
```

I need to query data in a certain period of time. For example, from 07:00:00 to 10:00:00

I made this query function:

```
public void dbQuery(String startTime, String stopTime, Integer number) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        String selection = null;
        
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Connected myDB: ---");

        selection = "number = " + "\'" + number + "\'"+ " and " +  "time between " + "\'" + startTime + "\'" + " and " +  "\'" + stopTime + "\'";

        c = db.query("MyDB", null, selection, null, null, null,null);
}
```

I read if date \ time data written like text type you can make casual queries, like if your data is in Date Java format.
But have this:

```
W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "07:00:00"
```

And my query is failed.

So, what is the way to make time query in SQLite ?

Answer (score 0):

> So, what is the way to make time query in SQLite ?

> I need to query data in a certain period of time. For example, from 07:00:00 to 10:00:00

Well from your data you wouldn't find any rows as 03:43:16 etc are not in the range. Otherwise your query works fine.

The issue with  is with *`W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "07:00:00"`* is not in the query but elsewhere. It would appear that you are trying to make a date from a time and the parse is rejecting it.

- (e.g. which month is 00 and what day in a month is 00)

This is happening elsewhere when you are trying to parse the time as a date.

**Demo**

Consider the following which

a) shows that your query works
b) demonstrates an improved query
d) demonstrates an example of getting the error you have encountered

```
@SuppressLint("Range")
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static final String LOG_TAG = "LOGDBINFO";
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    Cursor c;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbQuery("01:00:00","19:00:00",1);
        while(c.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG+"RUN1",
                    "Number is " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number")) +
                            " Date is " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")) +
                            " Time is " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time"))
            );
        }
        improvedQuery("01:00:00","19:00:00",1);
        while(c.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG+"RUN2",
                    "Number is " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("number")) +
                            " Date is " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")) +
                            " Time is " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time"))
            );
        }
        /* reposition the cursor  before the first row */
        c.moveToPosition(-1);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            try {
                Date ok = sdf.parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")) + " " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time")));
                //Date test = sdf.parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date"))); // Fails as no time
                Date test2 = sdf.parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time")));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void dbQuery(String startTime, String stopTime, Integer number) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        String selection = null;

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Connected myDB: ---");

        selection = "number = " + "\'" + number + "\'"
                + " and " +  "time between " + "\'" + startTime + "\'"
                + " and " +  "\'" + stopTime + "\'"
                ;

        c = db.query("MyDB", null, selection, null, null, null,null);
    }

    /* This Binds the values passed which reduces the chance for SQLite Injection and
        also encloses the passed values in single quotes as required
     */
    public void improvedQuery(String startTime, String stopTime, Integer number) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        c = db.query(
                "MyDB",null,
                "number =? AND time between ? AND ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(number),startTime,stopTime},
                null,null,null);
    }
}
```

When run the loop after your query logs :-

```
D/LOGDBINFO: --- Connected myDB: ---
D/LOGDBINFORUN1: Number is 1 Date is 2021-12-15 Time is 03:43:16
D/LOGDBINFORUN1: Number is 1 Date is 2021-12-15 Time is 03:54:35
D/LOGDBINFORUN1: Number is 1 Date is 2021-12-15 Time is 03:56:32
```

The after the imporoved query  logs :-

```
D/LOGDBINFORUN2: Number is 1 Date is 2021-12-15 Time is 03:43:16
D/LOGDBINFORUN2: Number is 1 Date is 2021-12-15 Time is 03:54:35
D/LOGDBINFORUN2: Number is 1 Date is 2021-12-15 Time is 03:56:32
```

However after not encountering an issue with the line :-

```
Date ok = sdf.parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date")) + " " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time")));
```

catches an exxception in the line :-

```
Date test2 = sdf.parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("time")));
```

This being the exception that you encountered i.e. the log shows:-

```
W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "03:43:16"
W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:362)
W/System.err:     at a.a.so70357434.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
```

- note that the last message details the exact line, in Android Studio it also has a link which if clicked takes you to the offending line.
- Hence why, when asking questions where there is an exception, that the stack/log be included.